# Is it legal to overrun one element of a struct to view another?

Tags: c++, c, standards

Given the following contrived example code:

```
struct abc
{
    int x[5];
    int y[5];
};

void main()
{
    struct abc test;
    test.y[0] = 10;
    printf("%n", test.x[5]);
}
```

The output of the program is 10.

While not the best programming practice, this does work. However, is this an artifact of the compiler and platform, or is this legal code? (i.e. defined by the C standard?)

Even if the result is not guaranteed to be 10, is there ever an instance where this would be "illegal" (i.e. writing to memory I do not "own")?

Comment: There is a very good chance that the same code is going to break if you try it with `char` instead of `int`, and keep an odd size of the array.

Comment: `void main()` is **not valid C or C++**.

Comment: Let me ask another question: why on earth would you think you **need** to do something like that ?

Comment: @KerrekSB: And yet many, many embedded environments expect a `void main(void)` where the return value of `main` has no meaning because programs are meant to run indefinitely after they are started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: As pointed out by others, this is not legal, as it results in undefined behaviour.  I've removed this sentence from my answer.

This has the potential to result in undefined behaviour.  You've allocated a memory chunk of 10 ints long in the struct abc, so indexing into the 5th (6th) item will take you to y[0] as you've noted in THIS specific case.

Where you can run into problems is when the C compiler packs the structure in a way that you do not expect.  This is called data packing or bit alignment.  When the computer wants to access memory from your data structure, it will attempt to do so in uniform chunks for the entire structure.  Let's use an example:

```
struct abc {
    int a;
    char b;
    int c;
};
```

What do you expect the size of this struct to be?  An int is 32 bits, and a char is 8 bits, so the total size should be 32 + 8 + 32 = 72 bits.  However, you will find that on many systems, this structure is actually 96 bits in size.  The reason is that char b gets bit packed on the end with an additional 24 bits to maintain a standard offset between variables.

This can be extremely confusing when you declare a structure in two different places, and one gets bit packed while the other does not due to compile time options or configuration.

Look up bit packing and data alignment or bit alignment for more information.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: I'm not sure accepting the only answer that doesn't mention "undefined behavior" was the right thing to do. Surely, this anwser seems to comfort you in your beliefs, but really you shouldn't do it.

Comment: It's *not* legal, in the sense that it gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: To paraphrase: `This is legal in the sense that it gives undefined behavior and may print everything` - well in my book that's the complete opposite of legal.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that this is indeed illegal in that it results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: The C++11 standard barely uses the word "legal", and doesn't define it. In every case where it does use it (that I can find), the thing it is describing as "illegal" is rejected by the compiler, or the thing it describes as "legal" is accepted and has defined behavior. So take your pick what you think it should mean, but for preference use standard terminology ("well-formed", "ill-formed", "UB")

Comment: Hmmm I think I agree with Steve Jessop.  If you try to access memory that is not "yours", i.e. smash the stack, then the compiler or the OS itself will likely complain if you have buffer overflow protection turned on.

Answer (score 12):

No, it's not legal nor guaranteed to work. The compiler could add padding into the struct, to aid in alignment, depending on the architecture, etc.

**Edit:** To sum up some of the stuff in these comments and clarify...

I do believe you "own" the memory there, since as edA-qa mort-ora-y points out, memcpy() of a struct needs/is expected to work. Where this is specifically guaranteed though, I'm not sure.

That being said, undefined behavior is something to avoid **at all costs.** What a program with undefined behavior does could change between two separate runs of the same code five seconds apart. It could cause subtle memory corruption in your program, a segfault, or run just fine, but there's no reason to ever use code that relies on undefined behavior.

Comment: It's legal, just not defined behavior.

Comment: This also violates aliasing rules.

Comment: @Pubby: What's your definition of "legal" (*"won't land you in jail"*?)

Comment: I do "own" the entire block of memory though, correct? i.e. there's nothing illegal about writing `test.x[5] = 10`, even if there's no guarantee that the value will appear at `test.y[0]`? I'm trying to distinguish between legal and a very, very bad idea.

Comment: @aix If it were strictly illegal then the compiler should choke on it.  Although I suppose since it's UB it could go either way.

Comment: Related reading: [Common gotchas when writing your own p/invoke](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/08/13/9867383.aspx)

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: what people meant here, is that even if you own the memory block, there is **no guarantee** about what you will read using this trick.

Comment: @Pubby: Writing `test.y[10] = 10;` would be illegal though, causing a segfault, but will compile.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: It will not necessarily cause a segfault. Anything could happen. This is what undefined behavior means and this is why you should avoid it.

Comment: I no longer think in C++11 this is undefined behaviour. This is a standard layout type and that means copying via memcpy is defined, thus there must be some guarantee about the memory in the padding space. Though I completely agree that value is undefined and has no guarantee about rolling over into the next member. But it must be safe to access the memory located there due to the standard layout requirements.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Nice to know. My concern is: perhaps it **is** safe in C++11, but is it really a good idea anyway ? I really fail to see why someone would need to do that.

Comment: @ereOn, I would assume curiosity. Just wait 'till the OP finds out he can also modify his own instructions ;)

Comment: I think that `test.x[5] = 10` is UB. `test.x+5` is the one-off-the-end pointer, and accessing through a one-off-the-end pointer is UB, regardless of whether you "own" the memory or not. However, if `test.x+5 == test.y` on your particular implementation, which most likely is publicly documented in the struct layout rules, then by good fortune you are using a valid pointer value after all, even though it was obtained in a way not guaranteed to produce a pointer you can access as an `int*`. OTOH `*(unsigned char*)(test.x+5) = 10` *is* allowed precisely because you own the memory.

Comment: Or to put it another way, @edA-qamort-ora-y: the fact that you can memcpy POD/standard layout objects means it's safe to access using `unsigned char*`, and also using `char*` in C++. I don't think it's guaranteed safe to access using `int*`, but I also don't expect it to fail to work on any "normal" implementation.

Comment: For C99, the only case that this can lead to UB is when the bit pattern stored at `x[5]` is a trap representation for `int`. So first, your platform has to have such trap (I don't know of any commodity architecture that has this) and then the corresponding bit must be uninitialized for some reason; either because you have padding between the members or because you didn't initialize `y[0]`. So the question if it is "legal" is more or less theoretical. More important is the question if this gives you the element that a naive reader may think it does: No, it doesn't, so it is extremely dangerous.

Comment: @JensGustedt Maybe my definition of UB is wrong, but if we have some padding there we may read completely different values every time we run the program. That sounds very much like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: @Voo, no it is not UB but the value is unspecified. These are two different things in C. UB means that anything can happen, from eating your harddrive to emtptying your bank account. Unspecific value means just that: you can have any value in the variable. This is why such things can go without notice for a long time. Things that are crashing the application immediately are much nicer :)

Comment: @Jens Where does the standard distinguish between "value is unspecified" and "this is UB"? I mean signed overflow is UB although it's rather similar to this situation.

Comment: The standard (C99) distinguishes between "undefined behavior" (3.4.3) and "unspecified behavior" (3.4.4). The later explicitly mentions "use of an unspecified value". And no an overflow is something different. If you start with a positive `int` value and only increment, e.g., a compiler is allowed to assume that the value will always be positive and may do optimizations in that sense. If the value is unspecific, the compiler can't and shouldn't assume anything.

Answer (score 5):

This is undefined behaviour - you are (un)lucky in this case. Further more (aside from the mentioned padding issue), there is the maintainability issue - it's incredibly fragile - what if someone sticks something else in between. I'm sure it's a contrived example, but the recommendation is - don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Technically the behavior is undefined.

> While not the best programming practice, this does work.

Undefined behavior means anything can happen including what you expect. It might well crash on other implementations.

Comment: More important (and a more convincing argument) than potential "crashing" is the fact that the compiler may make assumptions about your code when optimizing which you are violating.